# Creating a button style and adding a background

Tags: android, android-button

I want to create a style that changes the background of my button

I wrote this [Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX5s4.png) and it does what I want except it doesnt change the background of my button to the given drawable, it just stays this pale purple color. For context this is the drawable [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L32NQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of choosing your background color in drawable

you can use **android:backgroundTint="#YOURCOLOR"** or add the color Programmatically as said in this [Article](https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin-android/kotlin-android-button-background-color/#gsc.tab=0)